# Remote to MariaDB server which IP has port

Tags: mysql, mariadb, remote-server

I want to connect to VM server

Here is server IP:203.64.1.2:8080

MariaDB's port = 3306

I used this command:
`mysql -uroot -p123456 -h203.64.1.2:8080 -P3306`

It showed :`ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '203.64.1.2:8080' (11001)`

If I use this:
`mysql -uroot -p123456 -h203.64.1.2 -P8080`

show this:
`ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 0 "Internal error/check (Not system error)"`

Do I use wrong command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your port can't be 8080 and 3306 at the same time. You must pick one. Have you tried:

```
mysql -uroot -p123456 -h203.64.1.2 -P3306
```

?

Comment: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '203.64.1.2' (10061 "Unknown error")

Comment: Then you need to either assign a specific ip to the vm you want to refer to, or forward a port from the host machine to the vm for the mysql server. Otherwise it will be impossible for you to connect to the mysql server, just like it is behind a firewall.

Comment: OK, I see. I will try to. Thank you. :)